# How can I do printing in Java with layouts instead of low level coordinates?

Tags: java, swing, layout, printing, document

I need to do some printing from my Java Swing application. I have tried to use [Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html), but everything is very low level, and time-consuming. I have to specify the coordinates for every line that I want to print. It is also very lowlevel to use text, because I have to use [FontMetrics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) and calculate what space all text fills up.

Is there any easier way to to printing in Java? I would like to design the documents with something like layout managers instead. Any good library or API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) ([new location](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library))

Answer (score 2):

What kind of document are you looking to print to?

Like Maurice said [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) is a good library.  You can also use [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to work with Microsoft documents

Comment: I will print data form my application, to paper.